# Expanding the number of objects available for use in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I want to create an MKAnnotationView in my storyboard, but when I click on the [image] button, there is no option to add this.

Is there a way to import custom libraries or expand the list of objects available to use in the storyboard?

Everything I have searched on the topic returned results about adding stuff from the storyboard into viewController.swift or adding already available objects into the storyboard, so I obviously don't know the right words to search for if there are answers online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create everything on storyboard, you just add the mapView from storyboard to your view controller. But then in order to customize your mapView with annotations, or showing user location etc, you need to write some code.

I found the following tutorial very useful when I first started to learn about MapKit and location services in iOS. I'd suggest to go along with that and then you will have a basic understanding of how MapKit and it's features work.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/548-mapkit-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: I created a UIView in storyboard that is almost shaped like the annotation I want to create. Is there a way to use this UIView and place it inside my annotation?

Comment: Right now I'm concerned about the x and y coordinate

Comment: You can create your own uiview class with nib file for your annotation. But you still have to create them programmatically in your map, you can design the annotation in nib file and class file.